# Newly appeared symbols in ELF file when migrating from gcc 10 to gcc 12

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, elf

I am comparing two elf files produced from the *same exact c++ code base* but different gcc/g++ versions : `10.2` and `12.2`. Both are compiled using the `arm-none-eabi` flavor of gcc/g++ for an STM32 CPU.
I would like to understand why the new g++ version uses an extra 30kB of flash as I am constrained for flash size.

I have used the python module `elf_diff` to create the following table. It highlights symbols that appeared across the gcc version update.
In particular I do not know what to make of the top 3 contributors, either because they are too generic (`categories`) or too obscure (`d02f4`, `b02cf`).
I understand I am using libstdc++ (for things like std::array, I am otherwise excluding dynamic allocation and exceptions) which can be different in the two gcc versions.

I am looking for clues on ways to :

- claim back 30kB.
- convince me that the increase is unavoidable when using the newer compiler version.

[image]

Comment: what standard library implementation are you using? what compile options are you using?

Comment: I am using the default version that ships with the arm-none-eabi toolchain as downloaded for gnu/linux x86_64 from official website there: https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/arm-gnu-toolchain-downloads

Comment: 1. Learn to use `readelf` or `objdump`.  This will give textual information on binaries.  2. Read the release notes for the compiler versions.  There are dozens of  changes and defaults that have been changed.  Not using `-Os` and expecting the size to decrease and then analyzing at the binary level is not a good way to tackle this problem.  There are always embedded C++ options that can limit code sizes, **IF** you make trade-offs in language functionality.  However, gcc is primarily targeting big iron code base by default.  It takes work to make it function for embedded applications.

Comment: Another point, the STM32CubeIDE/Eclipse has code (de-)generation options.  These will be targeted to the toolchain that the IDE was released for.  Relying on these options to produce sane results for an upgraded compiler will not work well.  Also, you can use `c++filt` and make a better list than python `elf_diff`, if you take the time to understand how the tools work.